# Flawless transfer on PayPal classic does nothing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Everyhing works flawlessly with my PayPal classic implementation in the sandbox. (Marked as deprecated from jan 17 but still supported.) But it simply does not transfer money from the customer to the merchant.

```
  "payment": {
    "intent": "sale",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "amount": {
          "total": "1.21",
          "currency": "EUR",
          "details": {
            "subtotal": "1.08",
            "tax": "0.02",
            "handling_fee": "0.11"
          }
        },
        "description": "Description content."
      }
    ]
  }
```

After the customer agrees and executes the payment I receive an authorization:

```
  "onAuthorize": {
    "paymentToken": "EC-024873345P059811F",
    "orderID": "EC-024873345P059811F",
    "payerID": "4M6QNG7UDS626",
    "paymentID": "PAY-7W7465253T270972NLO5EG6A",
    "intent": "sale",
    "returnUrl": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/?paymentId=PAY-7W7465253T270972NLO5EG6A&token=EC-024873345P059811F&PayerID=4M6QNG7UDS626"
  }
```

I expect that the money transfer took place but nothing shows. No transactions, no errors, no nothing. As if nothing happened. I also expect that I get a notification if the transaction is not executed due to its deprecation. That is not the case. I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using the deprecated classic after all but the new Client Side Rest: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

It is close to classic, I only needed to add ...

```
return actions.payment.execute();
```

Then the actual transfer takes place. I am a happy coder now.